# Can someone help me with the syntax for CREATE TABLE?

Tags: mysql, ddl

Can anyone figure out why this isn't working. Do I need to have a definition for each column?

```
CREATE TABLE `wishlist` (
`wishlistID`,
`userID`,
`graveID`,
`graveyardID`,
PRIMARY KEY (`wishlistID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I edited the title of your question and added a tag. Why? want your questions and answers to be useful to others. Please try to describe your questions in a way that a search engine might find. And, please search first. It's possible somebody already answered a similar question.

Comment: At this point, a few minutes in the company of any recent, decent, basic, introductory book or tutorial will pay dividends.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is wrong with this create table statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186948/what-is-wrong-with-this-create-table-statement)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you must to define data types for each column in a table. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `wishlist` (
    `wishlistID` int(10) unsigned,
    `userID` int(10) unsigned not null,
    `graveID` smallint not null,
    `graveyardID` int(11),
    `description` varchar(255),
    `created_at` datetime,
PRIMARY KEY (`wishlistID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Note the number in parentheses following an INT declaration is almost entirely meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must declare a datatype for each column.

Maybe this will help you figure out what you want use for datatypes. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-tables.html

You might try this to get started.

```
CREATE TABLE wishlist (
  wishlistID UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  userID UNSIGNED INT,
  graveID UNSIGNED INT,
  graveyardID UNSIGNED INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (wishlistID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;
```

This looks like each column is a reference (foreign key) to another table. Explaining what you might want to know about  all those other tables is waaaaaaay beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: Why `UNSIGNED INT` instead of the more conventional `INT` or even `SERIAL`?

Comment: Yah get twice  as many surrogate primary key values with UNSIGNED. I know that's way in the future for OP, but not for me.

Comment: If you're anticipating *billions* of records, you may as well pull the pin and go `BIGINT`.